# How to merge two object include function in PHP

Tags: php

```
class Foo {
    public function sampleA(){
        echo "something ...";
    }
}

class Bar {
    public function sampleB(){
        echo "something ...";
    }
}

$objectA = new Foo();
```

I want to call $objectA->sampleB() directly, not $objectA->somevariable->sampleB();
How to do this?

Comment: That is impossible. Foo has no method `sampleB`. Your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you looking to mash these two objects up at runtime or design time?

Comment: runtime. I try to custom something in framework. I have consider about trait, extend ... but i don't have the best way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to simply change the class declaration:

```
class Foo extends Bar {
```

The other way around is also possible; it really depends on your use-case. [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) are also a possibility.

```
trait Bar {
    public function sampleB(){
        echo "something ...";
    }
}

class Foo {
    use Bar;

    public function sampleA(){
        echo "something ...";
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 You have beaten me `:)` Still, I think splitting classes into 2 traits is more convenient / suitable for this case.

Comment: @CORRUPT If that's what OP is after, then yes :)

Answer (score 3):

You may try to use [`traits`](http://php.net/traits) (php **5.4**+) for multiple inheritance:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');

trait Foo {
    public function sampleA(){
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

trait Bar {
    public function sampleB(){
        echo __METHOD__, PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Baz {
    use Foo, Bar;
}

$test = new Baz();
$test->sampleA();
$test->sampleB();
?>
```

Shows:

```
Foo::sampleA
Bar::sampleB
```

Comment: @Jack I just hope OP doesn't need to instantiate those classes. Then traits are doomed, unless `class cFoo { use Foo; } class cBar { use Bar; }`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a facade to the two classes;

```
class FooBar {
    protected $foo;
    protected $bar;

    public function __construct (Foo $foo, Bar $bar){
        $this->foo = $foo;
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

    public function sampleA(){
          return $this->foo->sampleA();
    }

    public function sampleB() {
          return $this->bar->sampleB();
    }
}
```